# Blades of Chaos at Level 5 but Chaos and Conflagation Goal Incomplete

Tags: god-of-war-2018

I've upgrade Blades of chaos to level 5 but the labor Chaos and Conflagration in the tab Goals remains incomplete, objective Chaos Flames collected shows 3 of 4.

- I've finished history,
- Killed all valkyries,
- No lost objects in workshop
- Images attached (sorry for bad resolution, I have game text in spanish language)

Is this a bug?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. This has been posted both on the [PS Forum](https://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/God-of-War/God-of-War-4-Chaos-and-conflagration-labor-bug/m-p/25686329) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GodofWar/comments/8l47gk/labour_bug_over_hereanyone_else/).

Unfortunately, no fix, or known cause has been found for this yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, is good to know is not something I missed.